# Error trying to upgrade Raspbian (Jessie)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

When trying to upgrade my Raspbian (8.0 jessie) on my Raspberry Pi 2 with `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I'm getting the following error:

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20.2/auto/Unicode/Collate/Collate.so' to 

'/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20.2/auto/Unicode/Collate/Collate.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.20.2-3+deb8u12) over (5.20.2-3+deb8u6) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/perl/5.20.2/unicore/lib/Nt/Nu.pl' to 

'/usr/share/perl/5.20.2/unicore/lib/Nt/Nu.pl.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
I've already done `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get clean`.

Answer (score 0):

The deb file itself is corrupt.
You can remove it, and run update/upgrade again. It will download a new version.

Like this:

```
cd  /var/cache/apt/archives

sudo rm perl_5.20.2-3+deb8u12_armhf.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```